# asp.net mvc with angular with multiple parameter ajax call HttpPostedFileBase file getting null value

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, httppostedfilebase

Here i send an object and a file from my angular service:

```
 $scope.addProject = function () {
        {
            var project = {};
            project["Id"] = $scope.Id;
            project["ProjectCode"] = $scope.ProjectCode;

            var file = $scope.myFile;
            projectModelService.saveProject(project,file)
            .success(function (data) {

            })
            .error(function (xhr) {
                $ngBootbox.alert('Error in saving data');
            });

        }
    };
```

and in my angular service:

```
saveProject: function (project) {
             var parameters = { project: project, file: file };

             var fdata = new FormData();
             fdata.append('file', file);

             var param = { project: project, file: fdata.append('file', file) };
            return $http({
                url: '/Project/CreateProject',
                method: 'POST',
                data: project
               // contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
               // processData: false, // Not to process data
               // transformRequest: angular.identity,
               // headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(param)

            })
        },
```

and in my Project/Createproject :

```
  public JsonResult CreateProject(Project project, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
     }
```

Now problem is in every situation my HttpPostedFileBase file return null. But if i pass the file by single parameter as :

```
 uploadProjectModelList: function (file) {
            var fdata = new FormData();
            var url = '/Project/UploadProjectFGModelListExcelFile';
            fdata.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(url, fdata, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            })
        }
```

it shows the file value but whenever using it to pass multiple parameter as like project object file are found but project object was null. how can i pass multiple parameter as a object and a file from ajax to asp.net controller in MVC5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the `project` parameter as part of the `FormData` payload:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
var url = '/Project/UploadProjectFGModelListExcelFile';
fdata.append('file', file);

fdata.append('project.Id', project.id);
fdata.append('project.Foo', project.foo);
fdata.append('project.Bar', project.bar);
fdata.append('project.Baz.Bazinga', project.baz.bazinga);
...

return $http.post(url, fdata, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
});
```

Standard field naming rules apply for the ASP.NET MVC model binder.

Comment: How can i pass full project obj and in controller how can i define it by parameter??